# jdbc empty resultset check not working

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

In the following java class i'm having a method authenticate, in which i'm using `resultSet.next()` method to check that whether the given userName and password exist in the database or not, but it is returning false even when the given userName and password exist in the database.

```
public boolean authenticate(String userName,String password){
//db connection code
    try {
      String query = "select user_name from registeredUser where user_name= ? AND password = ?";
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
          pstmt.setString(1, userName);
      pstmt.setString(2, password);
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
      if(rs.next()) {  
            System.out.println("True");
                return true;
          }  
      else return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return False;
    } finally {
      try {
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `next()` doesn't return what you expect, then either your data or your query is wrong.

Comment: 1. why do you return value from void method? 2. is there any exception?

Comment: oh really sorry return type of the method is boolean.

Comment: OK, why do you return String from method that returns boolean? in short, please post a short version of your real code. It will make it easier to detect a problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you pass the name that really exists? Because if there is a name in DB like "Bob" and if you pass the name "bob" it wiil return false

Comment: Yes i'm 100% sure that the given userName and password exist in the database.

Comment: Try the next query:
select count(*) from registeredUser where user_name= ? AND password = ?;
and check if return value not equals 0

Comment: @maks:Could you please elaborate the query you mentioned in previous comment?

Comment: Please don't type/edit code straight in the stackoverflow editor. You need to ensure that you post **real** compileable and executabele which reproduces exactly the problem you have.

Comment: I edited my origonal code to make it as short as possible to present it on the forum. But the above code is still returning false even if it exist in the database.

Comment: @BalusC:Ok next time i'll not do such mistake.

Comment: Show us the values in the database you're looking for and the values you're passing in. Trim values before pass in (userName.trim(), ...).

Comment: i'm having following values in the db.                         userName:usman,password:2 and i'm passing pstmt.setString(1,"usman"),pstmt.setString(2,"2");

Comment: Commit was not done in the database due to which queries were showing result in console but in jdbc code resultSet.next() was returning false.Thanks v v v much to all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your underlying DBMS you might have a problem with the case of username and password.

For most DBMS `MySecretPassword` is a different value than `mysecretpassword`.

So, in case your DBMS **is** case-sensitive and the user did not enter the username and password *exactly* the same it's stored in the database it is very likely that the SELECT returns nothing.

Comment: i'm passing values with matching case but it is still returning false.

Comment: @umash: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct database?

Comment: Anything that might help. According to what you have shown us, your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code:

```
public boolean authenticate(String userName,String password){
//db connection code
    try {
      String query = "select count(*) from registeredUser where user_name= ? AND password = ?";
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
          pstmt.setString(1, userName);
      pstmt.setString(2, password);
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
      rs.next();
      int count = rs.getInt(1);
      if(count != 0) {  
            System.out.println("True");
                return true;
          }  
      else return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return False;
    } finally {
      try {
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks v v v v much.Above method is returning false even when the entered values exist in the database.

Comment: So there are only 2 reasons why it return false: 1. as i mentioned above you pass incorrect values to the function(maybe values with spaces or different case as in DB); 2. if someone(from another connection) put that values to db and forgot to make a commit and you can't see this values from your connection

Answer (score 0):

In the comments to the OP you say "i'm having following values in the db. userName:usman,password:2" but your code says the user name field is called "user_name".

userName != user_name